# Added Passpoint not connecting

Tags: android, android-networking, android-network-security-config

I have added a passpoint configuration in my app on Android 11.
The add works perfectly but it doesn't connect.

I tried to get a list of which passpoints are added but get an empty list.

```
    val config = PasspointConfiguration()
    config.credential = Credential().apply {
        userCredential = Credential.UserCredential().apply {
            username = "******"
            password =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("*****".toByteArray())
            eapType = 21
            nonEapInnerMethod = "MS-CHAP-V2"
        }
        realm = "merki.local"

        certCredential = null
        caCertificate = myCertificate
        clientPrivateKey = null
        clientCertificateChain = null
    }
    config.homeSp = HomeSp().apply {
        fqdn = "meraki.com"
        friendlyName = "Meraki"
    }
        
    val bundle1 = Bundle()
    bundle1.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_LIST, suggestionsList)
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS)
    intent.putExtras(bundle1) 
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, 9999)
```

I get the popup asking me to confirm the adding and I click okay.

In the Activity I have the following:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    LOG.d("onActivityResult requestCode= ",requestCode, " resultCode= ", resultCode);
    if (requestCode == 9999){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // user agreed to save configurations: still need to check individual results
            if (data != null && data.hasExtra(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_RESULT_LIST)) {
                for(int code :  data.getIntegerArrayListExtra(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_RESULT_LIST)) {
                    switch (code) {
                        case ADD_WIFI_RESULT_SUCCESS:
                            List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> passpoints = ((WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).getNetworkSuggestions();
                            break;
                        case ADD_WIFI_RESULT_ADD_OR_UPDATE_FAILED:
                            break;
                        case ADD_WIFI_RESULT_ALREADY_EXISTS:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // User refused to save configurations
        }
    }

}
```

getNetworkSuggestions() returns an empty list as does getPasspointConfigurations()
and yet, the profile DOES appear in the list of saved networks.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

From your code I can see that you have not added passpoint configuration to your suggestion list.

```
var suggestionList: List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> = ArrayList()
val suggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
        .setPasspointConfig(p1)
        .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true) // Optional (Needs location permission)
        .build()
```

You can read more about passpoint configuration in [Blog about passpoint configuration in Android](http://gradlebuzz.com/passpoint-hotspot-2-0-integration-in-android/)

```
suggestionList.add(suggestion)
```

Then add this list to your bundle.